# Регулярное выражение для ввода строки с условием наличия хотя бы одной латинской буквы в любом месте

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть паттерн `[A-Za-z0-9]*`, позволяющий вводить любые буквы и цифры. Необходимо чтобы в строке была хотя бы одна буква в любом месте.

Comment: Честно говоря, тут можно обойтись без блоков просмотра. `^[0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$` или (для пустой строки) `^[0-9]*(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)?$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ваша вариант работает. Оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ

Comment: Проверил, `^[0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$` работает, второй - нет. Т.е. всё-таки если пустая строка должна находиться, не обойтись без блоков просмотра. Тогда это дубль, и надо закрыть вопрос.